# Do most native speakers understand most idioms?

Tags: idioms, email, non-native-english

I wrote to a friend, who is a native speaker of English about visiting her father. I wrote

> Should I give him a ring before visiting?

Here giving someone a ring is an English idiom which means calling someone on the telephone. However, from her reply, she apparently did not understand me:

> Just give him a card of encouragement.

I am learning English as a foreign language and it is discouraging when using a learnt idiom to a native speaker, he/she does not understand. This happened in an e-mail conversation so my pronunciation is not the reason.

Should I keep using idioms like this? Do most native speakers understand most English idioms?

Comment: Americans generally understand American idioms, Brits generally understand British idioms, and Australians generally understand Australian idioms. "Give him a ring" is a British idiom (we'd say "call him up"), and it's not guaranteed that Americans will understand it.

Comment: She may have been joking. Some people respond to idioms with a play on words. It’s a well-established form of humor.

Comment: I've no idea what a "card of encouragement" is. However, "give him a ring" might be deliberately misunderstood to refer to an engagement ring: a humorous response might be "You don't need to propose to him! Just phone him," when that's exactly what you had thought of doing. Perhaps that's what the "card of encouragement" is doing too.

Comment: Idiomatic expressions are little different from individual words, aphorisms, or broader cultural references: some are more widely understood than others. For instance, common North American sports expressions like *hat trick*, *Hail Mary pass*, *wheelhouse*, or *air ball* won't carry far outside North America. That said, I tend to agree with GlobalCharm in that the reply was probably intended humorously. It isn't as uncommon in the US to say *give him a ring* (or *call* or *buzz*) as it would be, for instance, to say *ring him*.

Comment: I have never heard *give somebody a ring before visiting* before. I'll mention I'm Canadian. In Canada, or at least my experience with it, and most likely the US, *ring* does not mean "phone call," it means a piece of jewellery. Although I would understand it in the right context (*give him a ring* ***to see if he's home***), where *ring* would mean that, that's not what I thought that expression meant when I initially read it. On the other hand, if I heard *ring him up*, I would understand that right away.

Comment: American English here. I can't imagine anyone not understanding *give him a ring* for *call him* in this context. I agree with @GlobalCharm that the response may have been a joke.

Comment: I think especially with young people, a telephone bell ringing is not something they experience every day. But it's unclear what the response meant - if only people thought to ask other people if they understood rather than posting here.

Comment: While it is difficult to be sure about the matter without knowing the context, it is possible that the OP's interlocutor did understand the question, and that what her response amounted to was 'you don't need to visit him at all (and so don't need to phone him before visiting), sending him a card is suffcient'.

Comment: @StuartF, it is true that young people are not familiar with phones that have actual bells, but they do choose **ring**tones for their phones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do **most** native speakers understand **most** idioms?

Yes, otherwise they would not exist. Some idioms may be specific to a particular group as a sociolect - these are often referred to as "jargon" and is not always generally understood.

As far as your specific example is concerned, "to give someone a ring" is common in British English and unlikely to be misunderstood.

The response is not particularly idiomatic and this could indicate a joke or a non-native speaker.